# Spring MVC - Open new page without reload

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a small app set up using Sring MVC and Sitemesh. When i click a link, a form, etc., i want it to open the new page without reloading the whole decorator page, just the decorator:body part. Is there any simple way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for fetching the page part without full page reloading

**UPDATED (04/05/2011):**

using JQuery for AJAX.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myapp/getpart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPart(Model model) {
  //...do something
  model.addAttribute("myObject", myObject);
  return "getPart";
}
```

View:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
<a id="myAnchor">get page part</a>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myAnchor').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.get('/myapp/getpart', function(data) {
        $('#container').html(data);
        alert('Data was fetched.');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I know very little about ajax, could you give a simple example of how i could do that?