# Issues with scripts when loading portion of page using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading portion of the page like described here:
[Spring MVC - Open new page without reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525662/spring-mvc-open-new-page-without-reload/5526817#5526817). Issue is that scripts executed at the beginning of page do not work for loaded html, because when scripts was executed html content was not loaded.

First script with issue is:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#coclevel1').change(getLevel2);
        $('#coclevel2').change(getCocItems);
        ...
    });
```

coclevel1 and coclevel2 are html selects.

Second script is [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/custom-form-elements.js) script from [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).

I'm developing Spring MVC 3.0 web application with Freemarker and JQuery.

How to apply scripts to loaded html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling `.change()` only attaches a handler to current elements. Using `.live()` will bind a handler to all current and future elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#coclevel1').live('change', function(){getLevel2});
    $('#coclevel2').live('change', function(){getCocItems});
    ...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped to find solution for first scripts issue. Could help me to solve issue with second scripts?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped to find solution for first scripts issue. Could help me to solve issue with second scripts?
custom-form-elements.js has window.onload = Custom.init. How can I run Custom.init to make workable for future elements. I've tried to comment window.onload = Custom.init; and add 


 $(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  $(window).live('load', initCustomForms);

  function initCustomForms() {
      Custom.init();
        }

but it doesn't work.