# How to refresh div using Scheduler in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to refresh the div using Scheduler in spring mvc and jsp.Without using javascript setInterval is it possible.?What i get it is

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute periodically
}
```

But Am not getting how to refresh the div/page using it.Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is for performing backend operations like delete some table entries if something didn't happen. This is used throughout an application - i.e; at application level, and what you are saying is one specific user level & i think you want something which can't happen via @scheduled.

Comment: Ok thanks man,for doing this any suggestion from your side please.

Comment: Post complete details. What you are actually trying to do.
Edit your question and add more details like the jsp and what task you are trying to perform.

Comment: Am not able to post code it's confidential. What i want is want to refresh the page div in every 1 second

Comment: At least you could post an example code which is kind of symmetric to what you are trying to achieve. And what ever the issue is, for that case, you can use angular, javascript, etc.

Comment: [only way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526817/2749470)

Comment: You can use web sockets for this.

Comment: Thank you for your all replies ..I did it..:)